# JS to display a message based on age selected on form

Tags: javascript, css, forms

I have a form with Date of birth select fields split into Day, Month and Year. If a user selects their date of birth that is less than 45 years old then i need to display a message to tell them they are too young and offer an alternative.

I managed to get it working by using display:none for the div element with the message and the following JS. However, i would like the element to go back to hidden again if the user changes their DOB to over 45.

I just realised now that if the user selects a year by mistake that makes them under 45 years old the message will appear, however, if they change to correct year (making them over 45 years old) the message does not disappear.

Please help.

```
window.onload = function my() {
  document.getElementById('dob-date-3-y').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('too_young');
    var minAge = 45;
    var bday = parseInt(document.forms[0]['dob-date-3-d'].value);
    var bmo = (parseInt(document.forms[0]['dob-date-3-m']) - 1);
    var byr = parseInt(document.forms[0]['dob-date-3-y'].value);
    var byr;
    var age;
    var now = new Date();
    tday = now.getDate();
    tmo = (now.getMonth());
    tyr = (now.getFullYear()); {
      if ((tmo > bmo) || (tmo == bmo & tday >= bday)) {
        age = byr
      } else {
        age = byr + 1
      };
    } {
      if ((tyr - age) < minAge) {
        modal.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: It may not be the answer, but it looks related at least, you've defined `byr` twice, with the latter overriding the former.

Comment: Could you provide a working example using code snippets? Including the HTML would help to fix the issues. Also tday, tmo and tyr are implicit global variables, which is considered error prone (google: Horror of Implicit Globals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing only the case if their age < minAge, so you need to add an `else` test which means the case where thier age is >= minAge then in this case set `modal.style.display = "none";` to hide it.

```
if ((tyr - age) < minAge) {
  modal.style.display = "block";
} else {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: What i thought, thanks bud. My programming is very minimal so i knew there was something missing at the end to return it back to display none.

Just wasn't sure if adding another else statement was gonna work.

But it now works! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
window.onload = function my() {
  document.getElementById('dob-date-3-y').addEventListener('change', 
    function() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('too_young');
    var minAge = 45;
    var bday = parseInt(document.forms[0]['dob-date-3-d'].value);
    var bmo = (parseInt(document.forms[0]['dob-date-3-m']) - 1);
    var byr = parseInt(document.forms[0]['dob-date-3-y'].value);
    var age;
    var now = new Date();
    tday = now.getDate();
    tmo = (now.getMonth());
    tyr = (now.getFullYear()); 
    if ((tmo > bmo) || (tmo == bmo & tday >= bday)) {
       age = byr
    } else {
       age = byr + 1
    }
    if ((tyr - age) < minAge) {
       modal.style.display = "block";
    }else{
       modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
};
```

I just removed extra brackets, unnecessary semicolons and added an else part to hide the modal.